# Pandas mass renaming columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a excel file which has a dates as column headers. 
The dates span to about 100 columns. I want to rename all these dates as Month1, Month2 and so forth. 
i am new to Pandas and Python.

One way I found was to create a list of new column names and then replace the old with the new,
however this means I have to type out over 100 columns.

Is there a way to have a condition e.g. from column 7 onwards rename all column headers to Month1 + 1?

[image: Example]

as per month above I have this going upto 2028 so need to rename it all. i.e. month1 to month 12 then restart from April month1-12

I have something like this;

> ```
>  df_cols = ['Project Name', 'Project Principal', 'Value', 'value as per Vision', 'Proability', 
> 'Account', 'Phase', 'Number', 'ProjectType', 'Rolling 12mnths', 'Month0', 'Month1', 'Month2', 
> 'Month3', 'Month4', 'Month5', 'Month6', 'Month7', 'Month8', 'Month9', 'Month10', 'Month11', 
> 'Month12', 'Total']
> ```

```
 df.columns = df_cols
```

Comment: Do you want to change "Apr-20" to "May-20", "May-20" to "June-20" and so on? If so, show your original columns using print in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, we can create a dictionary using `pd.to_datetime` to get the Month Number.

I've used a psuedo list but you'll need to amend the

`format='%B_%Y')` to `format='%b_%Y')`

or whatever format your column name is.

## setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar

year_cols = ['colA','colB'] + [f"{c}_{i}" for i in range(2020,2028) for c in calendar.month_name[1:]] 

nums = np.random.randint(0,500,size=len(year_cols))

df = pd.DataFrame([nums],columns=year_cols)
```

---

```
print(df.iloc[:,:7]) # print 7 columns

   colA  colB  January_2020  February_2020  March_2020  April_2020  May_2020
0   168   296           288            298         420         172       199
```

## Create a dictionary.

```
rename_dict = {i : f"Month{pd.to_datetime(i,format='%B_%Y').strftime('%m')}" 
               for i in df.iloc[:,2:].columns}
```

---

```
for k,v in rename_dict.items():
    if v == 'Month01':
        print(f'{k} -- > {v}')

January_2020 -- > Month01
January_2021 -- > Month01
January_2022 -- > Month01
January_2023 -- > Month01
January_2024 -- > Month01
January_2025 -- > Month01
January_2026 -- > Month01
January_2027 -- > Month01
```

---

## rename columns.

```
df = df.rename(columns=rename_dict)
```

---

```
print(df.iloc[:,:7]) # print 7 columns




   colA  colB  Month01  Month02  Month03  Month04  Month05
0   168   296      288      298      420      172      19
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for you're help can you please explain this line to me?

Comment: year_cols = ['colA','colB'] + [f"{c}_{i}" for i in range(2020,2028) for c in calendar.month_name[1:]]

Comment: @RegChand this is just a list comprehension I was just making some dummy data as you provided none (: make sure you provide some sample data next time. if you print it out or just strip back the outer loop you'll see I'm just creating a bunch of months from yeear 2020 till 2028